# Why does yii2 try to connect to mysql when I have not configured it to?

Tags: php, sqlite, yii, yii2

This is what I did:

- I downloaded the yii2 advanced template.
- Ran php init.
- Configured each of main-local.php files in

  - environments/dev/common/config
  - environments/prod/common/config
  - common/config

I added the following to the 'components'

```
'db' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'sqlite:/path/to/sqlitedbs/yayr.sq3',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
],
```

I configured the apache vhosts as explained in the readme.

Running `yii migrate` created the sqlite database file in the configured location with no errors.

What breaks is when I go to the frontend app and try to submit the sign up form, it gives me this error:

```
Exception
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
↵
Caused by: PDOException

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

in /home/johnsmith/dev/test/yayr/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php at line 579
```

The full stack trace can be seen: http://pastebin.com/KEKH1zbM

I have used my IDE to search for every location that a mysql dsn exists. The only place is in `/tests/codeception/config/config.php` which should not be called by submitting a form. To double check, I commented out the config, and it didn't help.

I also tried setting `'driverName' => 'sqlite',` in the config, but that did not make any difference. Neither did commenting out the username, password, or charset parameters.

None of the functions referenced by the stack trace appear to manually call MySQL. They all look for the configured dsn.

So, why does Yii think it can even try to connect to MySQL? Doesn't ActiveRecord abstract out all the SQL so that it won't matter if I'm using MySQL or sqlite?

How do I get past this issue? Using sqlite would make initial development a lot easier.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you see in `Yii::$app->db->driverName`?

Comment: Well, I was trying to syslog that information out, but can't get the syslog function to run. I think there's some kind of caching, but as far as I can see I've turned it off, and there are no runtime/cache directories. Anyway, I did a search of the entire project, and driverName is not being set anywhere. If that helps.

Answer (score 4):

**Basics of the Yii2 advanced template**

- You have the environments-folder containing you actual config files
- The frontend- and backend-folders hold copies of those "local"-files, depending on which environment you selected, they get copied from dev or prod

Now what does that mean? If you perform changes on ANY file within the envirnments folder, you have to re-init your application. You simply do this by opening a console, navigate to the base folder of your application and call the `init`-command. You will then be asked which envirnment you want and what files to overwrite.

After that you should see your changes beeing reflected in the frontend- and backend-folder. The idea behind this is to prevent if/else-structures within the config files and have a clean application. By the way: the `index.php` within the web-folders gets copied the same way. That way you could even customize this...and therefore the way the application gets loaded initially.

**Back to your problem**

For me it looks like you changed the settings within the `environments/.../local-...`-configfile, which is right...but then didn't re-init the application. That way the config file within the front- and backend still contain your old settings.

**Documantation of the advanced template**

Everything is very well documented here:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md

Answer (score -3):

After **init** command

Create a new database and add it in **common/config/main-local.php**

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your-db',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

Apply **yii migrate**  in console command!

It'll create the tables for the application to work

Comment: The point is I am not using mysql. At all. Configuring a mysql db is not going to solve my problem.

Comment: That is wrong. You should only change the *-local files wirhin the environments folder. Otherwise you defeat the purpose of the advanced template and your changes will be overwritten the next time to you execute the init-command.